# Add a new row in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable, dataset

next code shows a table filled (a gridview) with 5 columns and several rows. It's running well

```
while (drCLientes.Read())
{
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.ID = "myGridID";
cong.Open();
da = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cong);
ds = new DataSet("Clientes");
da.Fill(ds, "Clientes");
cong.Close();
gv.DataSource = ds.Tables["Clientes"];
gv.DataBind();
}
```

After this code, the result is this:

<sub>Table that I have</sub>

[image: Table that I have]

Now I need to add a new row, in the first position. The first column empty. The second and third one columns must be combined. The same with the 4th and 5th ones. Here is an image with the table that I need:

<sub>Table that I need</sub>

[image: Table that I need]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Repeater](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.aspx) instead of GridView.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repList" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repList_ItemCommand">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;"
            width="100%">
            <thead style="text-align: center;" class="Gridheader">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="2">Sequence</td>
                    <td colspan="4">Student</td>
                    <td colspan="3">Lesson</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">Point</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Surname</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>Class</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Teacher</td>
                    <td>Time</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="lblSequence" runat="server" >
                </asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblStudentName" runat="server" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblStudentSurname" runat="server" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblStudentAge" runat="server" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLessonClass" runat="server" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLessonName" runat="server" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLessonTeacher" runat="server" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLessonTime" runat="server" >
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLessonPoint" runat="server" >
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </tbody> 
    </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and Code Behind;

```
public void rptr_OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord objRow = (System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord)e.Item.DataItem;

        Label lblAnswer = e.Item.FindControl("lblSequence") as Label;
        lblAnswer.Text = objRow["Sequence"].ToString();

        Label lblStudentName = e.Item.FindControl("lblStudentName") as Label;
        lblStudentName.Text = objRow["StudentName"].ToString();

        ...
        ..
        .
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to create the gridview in the code view, because I have to render 1 table and 1 chart for hundred of clients... I´m not creating the controls in the designer view...

Comment: I try the Furkan Ekinci idea. The code doesnt show the table..I have something wrong. I need to write the code in the code view instead the designer view.

while (drClients.Read())
{
  TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
  table.Rows.Add(row1);
  TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
  row1.Cells.Add(cell1);

  Repeater rep = new Repeater();
  rep.ID = "myRepeater";
  cong.Open();
  OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlGrid, cong);
  OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
  rep.DataSource = dr;
  rep.DataBind();
  cell1.Controls.Add(rep);
  dr.Close();
  cong.Close();
}

Comment: With the code of Furkan Ekinci I get only one table
[link](http://s19.postimg.org/81fr1holv/sover.jpg)
But I have a loop.... I must create the header in the code view...
[link](http://s19.postimg.org/jf2acoz4j/soverbucle.jpg)
I think we are near of the end... Regards

Comment: Your tables look like same so you can create a user control and replace repeater code into user control.

Comment: Could you say me the way to call the user control in my loop, from my code view? Thanks...

Comment: If anyone knows how to display the table shown for the repeater control as often as you repeat in a loop, I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I´ve created [this user control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms366541(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) and the result is [this table](http://s19.postimg.org/gg510flcj/control.jpg) Instead to drag my control, I´ve tried [create a new instance in the code view](http://s19.postimg.org/5ul5off0z/code.jpg) but this doesnt work...